# How to emit an event from command line on running node.js app

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node.js and trying to solve the specifc task. To do so I need to know, how to trigger an event from command line. Let's say I have a function in node.js app, that I want to be runned every time I trigger it by command line.

```
event.on('block',() => {
    console.log('New block found')
});
```

and the emitter

```
function blockn() {
    event.emit('block')
}
```

I know, that I can run function from command line, with something like

```
node -e 'require("./myfile").blockn()'
```

But if I do so, it just runs the app once and then stops. But I need it to be running continously calling function every time the command line triggers the event.

Comment: Not to be 'that guy' but you can't, really. Why are you using `node -e`? What are you trying to accomplish?